# Release a lock before waiting, and re-acquire it after

Tags: c#, java, multithreading, locking

**In Java, you can associate multiple `Condition` objects to a single `ReentrantLock`. What would the C# equivalent be?**

**Real-world example:** The example implementation in the [Java `Condition` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) uses two `Condition` objects, `notFull` and `notEmpty`, tied to the same lock. How could that example be translated to C#?

**Background**: I often find Java code using two `Condition` objects to signal various states, associated to the same `Lock`; in C#, it seems that you can either

- call `Monitor.Enter` on an object, and then `Monitor.WaitOne`/`Monitor.Pulse`, but that's just one condition.
- use multiple `Auto/ManualResetEvent` objects, but these cannot atomically reacquire a given lock after waiting.

**Note**: I can think of one way: using `Monitor.WaitOne`/`Monitor.PulseAll` on a single object, and checking for the condition after waking up; that's what you do in Java as well to protect against spurious wake-ups. It doesn't really do, though, because it forces you to call `PulseAll` instead of `Pulse`, since `Pulse` might wake up a thread waiting on another condition. Unfortunately, using `PulseAll` instead of `Pulse` has performance implications (threads competing for the same lock).

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are doing new development and can do .NET 4 or above, you'll be better served by the new concurrent collection classes, like [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

But if you can't make that move, and to strictly answer your question, in .NET this is somewhat simplified imho, to implement a prod/cons pattern you would just do wait and then pulse like below (note that I typed this on notepad)

```
// max is 1000 items in queue
private int _count = 1000;

private Queue<string> _myQueue = new Queue<string>();

private static object _door = new object();

public void AddItem(string someItem)
{
    lock (_door)
    {
        while (_myQueue.Count == _count)
        {
            // reached max item, let's wait 'till there is room
            Monitor.Wait(_door);
        }

        _myQueue.Enqueue(someItem);
        // signal so if there are therads waiting for items to be inserted are waken up
        // one at a time, so they don't try to dequeue items that are not there
        Monitor.Pulse(_door);
    }
}

public string RemoveItem()
{
    string item = null;

    lock (_door)
    {
        while (_myQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            // no items in queue, wait 'till there are items
            Monitor.Wait(_door);
        }

        item = _myQueue.Dequeue();
        // signal we've taken something out
        // so if there are threads waiting, will be waken up one at a time so we don't overfill our queue
        Monitor.Pulse(_door);
    }

    return item;
}
```

**Update:**  To clear up any confusion, note that [Monitor.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.wait.aspx) releases a lock, therefore you won't get a deadlock

Comment: Yup, that's right in the case of queues, but it doesn't answer the question fully; it only works because your conditions (`== 0, == _count`) are mutually exclusive, so the two waits won't happen at the same time.

Comment: The code above is not correct. You need to replace Pulse with PulseAll. Consider the following scenario: The queue is full and has 2 producers and 1 consumer. Consumer consumes one item then wakes procuder1, producer1 produces one item then wakes producer2. The queue is full again and we have a dead lock.

Comment: @user2266486 I disagree, if the queue is full, two producers are waiting, on pulse will wake one thread, and one item gets inserted and the queue is full again, if you do `PulseAll` then your queue will have more than your max number of items, and if your queue is not full to start with, you won't have two producers waiting.  Also the prod won't wait if the queue is not full, and the cons won't wait if the queue is not empty

Comment: @Clément maybe I misunderstood your question, but the sample (link) you provided is doing the same thing in Java's way, this is doing it in .NET's way.  Basically there is no need for the `NewCondition` objects, in .NET you use `Monitor` to wait and signal on a shared/common object

Comment: @Jason If the queue is full and you wake only ONE thread, you are not guaranteed that thread is a consumer. It might be a producer and you get stuck.

Comment: @user2266486 you are correct, the thread that gets waken up is not guaranteed to be a consumer.  **BUT** if it's a producer and the queue is full, our while loop will kick back in, and we will wait again, and if it's the other way, the consumer will see the queue is empty it will kick back in and wait again   :)  It's been a while since I had to write a prod/cons, but I'm sure the logic is pretty close to being correct without any threading bug

Comment: @user2266486 Jason's code is correct, because both conditions are exclusive.

Comment: @Jason You're right that this is the right way to go for a queue. The thing is, Java makes it obvious (by using two conditions) that there will be no problems with waking up only one of the thread, and that the wrong thread won't be woken up. On the other hand, C# forces you to reason about the execution flow in a slightly subtle way (hence user2266486's mistake); hence my question: is there a more explicit way to have two conditions associated to the same lock ? For the record, my usual language is c# more than java; I was just seduced by the Java way of doing it.

Comment: @Clément Not with `Monitor`, however you can use Events, like Manual/AutoResetEvents, having said that, maybe the link you provided is not a good example for what you're trying to ask.  Going by the code on that link, they are also doing `while x == 0` and `while x == maxCount`, so we are still doing the checking and loop, yet using different objects (called Condition) to wait and signal each other, which in my opinion is messier and not as intuitive

Comment: @Jason Did you see the "Background" and "Notes" section in my question? They mention the Events and why they won't do, and also why there's the while loops in the Java version

Comment: @Clément yes, but to be clear I did not say you were wrong or that you missed that.  The point is, the Java code you're pointing to seem to still use the loop/check logic which seems pretty pointless if the separate condition objects are being used and if they are actually needed, then it's illogical how the separate condition objects make it better since at the end of the day you still need to do the same check.  I'd assume in coding, clearer and fewer lines of code is better than more lines of (perhaps confusing) code, assuming they accomplish the exact same thing  :)

Comment: Sorry guys if I sound too insistent, the above code is not correct. @Jason "if it's a producer and the queue is full, our while loop will kick back in, and we will wait again" Who would wake up the awaiting consumers after this? If there are no spurious wakeups, they'll keep waiting forever. This situation is likely to happen if the queue is small and number of producers >> number of consumers or the orhet way (queue is large and number of consumers >> number of producers)

Comment: @Jason I've tested your implementation as follows: Set the maximum queue size to 1 (_count=1), create one consumer thread and 10 producers threads and start them all, let them run for 10s and observe how many items got produced/consumed. On my machive I get a very low number (between 1 and 20 items) which clearly shows there is a problem.

Comment: @Jason: I get what you mean; for the record though, the reason the Java code has these while loops is spurious wake-ups, as advised in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

@Jason If the queue is full and you wake only ONE thread, you are not guaranteed that thread is a consumer. It might be a producer and you get stuck.

Comment: Can't figure out how to delete this

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across much C# code that would want to share state within a lock. Without rolling your own you could use a `SemaphoreSlim` (but I recommend `ConcurrentQueue(T)` or `BlockingCollection(T)`).

```
public class BoundedBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _locker = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);
    private readonly int _maxCount = 1000;
    private readonly Queue<T> _items;

    public int Count { get { return _items.Count; } }

    public BoundedBuffer()
    {
        _items = new Queue<T>(_maxCount);
    }

    public BoundedBuffer(int maxCount)
    {
        _maxCount = maxCount;
        _items = new Queue<T>(_maxCount);
    }

    public void Put(T item, CancellationToken token)
    {
        _locker.Wait(token);

        try
        {
            while(_maxCount == _items.Count)
            {
                _locker.Release();
                Thread.SpinWait(1000);
                _locker.Wait(token);
            }

            _items.Enqueue(item);
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            try
            {
                _locker.Release();
            }
            catch(SemaphoreFullException) { }

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _locker.Release();
            }
        }
    }

    public T Take(CancellationToken token)
    {
        _locker.Wait(token);

        try
        {
            while(0 == _items.Count)
            {
                _locker.Release();
                Thread.SpinWait(1000);
                _locker.Wait(token);
            }

            return _items.Dequeue();
        }
        catch(OperationCanceledException)
        {
            try
            {
                _locker.Release();
            }
            catch(SemaphoreFullException) { }

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _locker.Release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that basically the same as using a single object to `Wait` on? The code doesn't make it clear that you have two distinct condition, nor do the signalling affect only certain waiting threads; plus you're waiting actively by polling through `SpinWait`, doesn't that have performance implications?

Comment: There is no guarantee which thread (producer or consumer) gets the lock. The `Thread.SpinWait` reduces the lock contention, so threads that aren't making progress don't consume the lock as much.

Comment: I checked out the source for the `ReentrantLock` and it breaks down to a double lock with priority.